# Detect if Java application was run as a Windows admin

Tags: java, windows, admin, privileges

I have a Java application. Is there anyway I can tell if the process was run with admin privileges, on Windows 7.

Comment: I tested my answer in Linux. It's probably not OS-dependent, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found this code snippet online, that I think will do the job for you.

```
public static boolean isAdmin() {
    String groups[] = (new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem()).getGroupIDs();
    for (String group : groups) {
        if (group.equals("S-1-5-32-544"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It ONLY works on windows, and comes built in to the core Java package. I just tested this code and it does work. It surprised me, but it does.

The SID S-1-5-32-544 is the id of the Administrator group in the Windows operating system.

[Here is the link](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2010/10/21/detect-if-windows-user-has-admin-rights-using-java/) for more details of how it works.

Comment: Good ol' S-1-5-32-544. I should have thought of that.

Comment: ... And only with a Sun JVM due to private classes.

Comment: Note this snippet tests whether the active user is an Administrator, instead of whether the user has launched the application as an elevated process!

Comment: This doesn't work if the application is ran with normal rights on the administrator account. Still returns true...

Comment: This code will likely only work with Oracle JRE and is not guaranteed to work with any update to the JRE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Answer (score 37):

I've found a different solution that seems to be platform-independent. It tries to write system-preferences. If that fails, the user might not be an admin.

As [Tomáš Zato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-zato) suggested, you might want to suppress error messages caused by this method. You can do this by setting `System.err`:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import static java.lang.System.setErr;
import static java.util.prefs.Preferences.systemRoot;

public class AdministratorChecker
{
    public static final boolean IS_RUNNING_AS_ADMINISTRATOR;

    static
    {
        IS_RUNNING_AS_ADMINISTRATOR = isRunningAsAdministrator();
    }

    private static boolean isRunningAsAdministrator()
    {
        Preferences preferences = systemRoot();

        synchronized (System.err)
        {
            setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream()
            {
                @Override
                public void write(int b)
                {
                }
            }));

            try
            {
                preferences.put("foo", "bar"); // SecurityException on Windows
                preferences.remove("foo");
                preferences.flush(); // BackingStoreException on Linux
                return true;
            } catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return false;
            } finally
            {
                setErr(System.err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but I suggest that you cache the status into private static variable. It's not gonna change within one instance of the program.

Comment: @TomášZato You're definetly right that it won't change, but I wanted to make the code-example as short as possible

Comment: One more thing - the function keeps producing output, such as `Kvě 07, 2015 1:49:14 ODP. java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.` Is it possible to surpress these?

Comment: @TomášZato I improved my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Unfortunatelly, I can't upvote you a second time. Hopefully, someone else will.

Comment: This is the true solution that works. Suppression is important. +1

Comment: Note that the second code block in the answer throws a `NullPointerException`, due to `System.setErr(null)`. To fix that, use a dummy output stream instead: `System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
@Override
public void write(int i) throws IOException { }
}));`

Comment: The line `synchronized(systemErr)`  has no effect if the other Threads doesn't synchronize to `System.err` too.

Comment: +1 because this detects (what I think is called) administrative context, not just administrative users.  I am an administrator on my PC but most of the time I am not running programs with administrative rights.  For the above to return true, I must execute my program using `Run as Administrator`, which is different than just running a program as a user who is part of the administrators group.

Comment: Setting that empty error stream did not work for me, I still got the error output. Since Java 11, `OutputStream` has a built-in static method to create a "null output stream", though, accessed via `nullOutputStream()`. That one works. Maybe it's because a different overload for `write()` is called on it, while this answer only overrides one of them. The built-in null stream one overrides all of them.

Comment: Also, setting the error stream back to `System.err` also didn't work for me. I think `setErr()` already sets a new "standard" output stream? So `System.err` after that just refers to our "null stream" again. Saving the current `System.err` stream in a variable before calling `setErr()`, and then setting it back to that in the `finally {}` block, worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

There is not such a facility available in the Java Runtime Environment, but might be in a platform-dependent native routine.  Note that usually the best way to be certain is to actually try to do it, and see if it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Only by attempting an operation which requires such access (like binding a low-numbered port, or opening a known-to-be-protected file).

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. I attempted to create a test file in program files and caught IOException (Access is Denied)... new File(System.getenv("programfiles")+"/test.tst").createNewFile()

Answer (score 2):

The method from the answer marked best worked nicely for me until the point when I had to build the code in Jenkins on a Linux machine.  com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem() is not available there and using sun packages is generally considered a bad practice:
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: Grab the “rt.jar” from your windows machine. Add it to the class path on your Linux machine. Then have code inside your app that can see if its a windows PC, execute the accepted answer, if its Linux, run the Linux answers from this question. First solution that comes to mind. For me, I just needed to do this on Windows, so I didnt have this problem. Its one of those things where Java kind of sucks at doing. Just a side note, you should add this as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the rt.jar! I will give it a try. PS:I know, that this should have been a comment, but unfortunately, due to the somewhat weird way stackoverflow gives permissions, with my current reputation I am only allowed to comment on my own answers/questions =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution on Windows 10, I guess that it runs properly on other Windows OS too.

```
public static boolean isAdmin() {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(process.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        printStream.println("@echo off");
        printStream.println(">nul 2>&1 \"%SYSTEMROOT%\\system32\\cacls.exe\" \"%SYSTEMROOT%\\system32\\config\\system\"");
        printStream.println("echo %errorlevel%");

        boolean printedErrorlevel = false;
        while (true) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            if (printedErrorlevel) {
                int errorlevel = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
                return errorlevel == 0;
            } else if (nextLine.equals("echo %errorlevel%")) {
                printedErrorlevel = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below code worked out for me**

Command prompt command

```
net user
```

Java code

```
public static  boolean isAdmin() {
        StringBuilder outputbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe","/c" ,"net user");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            outputbuilder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println(outputbuilder.toString());
    return outputbuilder.toString().contains("Administrator");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could do this:

`System.getenv().get("USER")`

And see which user started the process.

When I run it as me I get "goran", when I run it with sudo I get "root". Works on Linux.
Probably what was needed.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting, let me try this and see what it does on windows. If it says "admin" this will work.

Comment: And please, post your results. I'd really like to know if this is OS-independent

Comment: On Windows 7, I get a null if I run this code. However, if I run System.getProperty("user.name"), I get my username. But, this still does not tell if I am admin or not.

Comment: Interesting. Try getting all the properties: `System.out.println(System.getenv());` Maybe, there is something else.

Comment: Also try: `System.out.println(System.getProperties());`

Comment: Ok, based on what you and Codemwnci said, this obviously works quite differently on Windows, so you'll have to do the try-and-see thing others suggested.

Comment: Using getenv(), the key is USERNAME, so your code would be System.getenv().get("USERNAME"), the result is the same as System.getProperty("user.name")

Comment: Well, my getenv contains both keys. Until now i didn't even notice "USERNAME"