# Application run another jar file

Tags: java

I have a problem because I have a application (jar) which run other application(jar) which download some files and on win8 I have a error **ACCESS DENIED**. I know if I run my application as admin everything works fine but how to make that user will not do nothing and i will work? Edit registry is bad way someone have other solution?

Comment: So you need to ask the admin how to resolve this.

Comment: I would start by reading (and posting) the complete error message. I doubt you only get ACCESS DENIED.

Comment: If you want to run a jar as admin then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832736/start-command-prompt-cmd-from-java-as-administrator