# Java on Windows: Test if a Java application is run as an elevated process (with Administrator privileges)

Tags: java, windows, eclipse-rcp, privileges, administrator

**Situation**

I have an (Eclipse RCP-based) Java application running on multiple platforms. I got this figured out on all platforms except Windows.

*Installer*: My application installer is always run in elevated mode, so it can install the application to `C:\Program files\MyProduct`. From a user perspective, this means the installer can only be executed by an Administrator and the UAC will ask for confirmation. This works fine.

*Normal usage*: The application **can be launched by normal users**. No administrator privileges should be required. This works fine.

*Auto-update*: The **auto-update** functionality also writes to `C:\Program Files\MyProduct` and therefore also **requires administrator privileges**. That's why the application, while it can be launched as a normal application too, MUST be run as an elevated process to auto-update. From a user perspective, it should be '*Run as administrator*' to auto-update.

**Question**

I would like a **runtime check** to see if my **Java process is in *elevated mode*** (i.e. to see if it was '*Run as administrator*'.

Note it may be a Windows-only solution. Using the Java reflection API, I can check for the Windows- and/or implementation-specific classes at runtime.

**Research**

I only found this question on StackOverflow:
[Detect if Java application was run as a Windows admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350356/detect-if-java-application-was-run-as-a-windows-admin)

However, that solution returns whether the active user is a member of the Administrator group. The user may still have my application launched in non-elevated mode. I have verified this.

**Note**

I know that an Eclipse RCP application will automatically install updates in the user directory, when he or she has no administrator privileges, but I want to block that case.

I want to allow user-specific configuration (which works fine), but allowing user-specific updates would leave too much mess after uninstallation.

Comment: Would it be enough just to check if you have write access to the install directory? This what the Eclipse location manager does when deciding where to put things.

Comment: That's how I solve this on Unix-based systems. Write a file, delete the file, if IOException return false, else return true. However, this test seems to pass on Windows when an administrator runs the application in non-elevated mode! I tested this manually: I can create a new project with my application and save it in the installation directory. Note a different (e.g. Word) file cannot be saved there. However, the Eclipse RCP update still moves to a private user directory! I guess because it has to modify and remove files as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Eclipse `LocationManager` does to determine if it can write to the install directory:

```
public static boolean canWrite(File installDir) {
    if (installDir.canWrite() == false)
        return false;

    if (!installDir.isDirectory())
        return false;

    File fileTest = null;
    try {
        // we use the .dll suffix to properly test on Vista virtual directories
        // on Vista you are not allowed to write executable files on virtual directories like "Program Files"
        fileTest = File.createTempFile("writtableArea", ".dll", installDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //If an exception occured while trying to create the file, it means that it is not writable
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (fileTest != null)
            fileTest.delete();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note the attempt to create a dll

Comment: Thanks for the information! I got it working with a similar approach. I now try rename a file (e.g. configuration/config.ini), which gives the same results as yours. However, I am still curious on how to get the elevated Windows status from Java, so I'll leave the question open for now. :)

Comment: I was wondering why I got a DLL file with a spelling mistake in my eclipse directory.

The word is "writable" and I'm on Linux so why are you writing this anyway?!

Answer (score 5):

Using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) and the [Win32 IsUserAnAdmin function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class WindowsAdminUtil {

   public interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {

      boolean IsUserAnAdmin() throws LastErrorException;
   }
   public static final Shell32 INSTANCE =
           Platform.isWindows() ?
           (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("shell32", Shell32.class) : null;

   public static boolean isUserWindowsAdmin() {
      return INSTANCE != null && INSTANCE.IsUserAnAdmin();
   }
}
```

According to the MS docs, IsUserAnAdmin() might not exist in future versions of Windows. So an even better method would be to use JNA to call the [CheckTokenMembership function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, doing that is more complex, so the above code is what I am using today.