# Run Java application as administrator on Windows

Tags: java, windows, uac, elevated-privileges

I am writing an installer in Java that will accordingly require elevated privileges to access the Program Files directory.  Based on information that I've found online, I've written an implementation as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (!checkPrivileges()) { // spawn a copy w/ elevated privileges
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p = runtime.exec(
                "runas /profile /user:Administrator \"java -cp . main.Main\"");
        } catch (IOException e) { ... }
    } else {
        // Run with elevated privileges
    }
}
```

The test that I'm using to check for privileges is modified slightly from an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631597/java-on-windows-test-if-a-java-application-is-run-as-an-elevated-process-with) and looks like this:

```
private static boolean checkPrivileges() {
    File testPriv = new File("C:\\Program Files\\");
    if (!testPriv.canWrite()) return false;
    File fileTest = null;
    try {
        fileTest = File.createTempFile("test", ".dll", testPriv);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (fileTest != null)
            fileTest.delete();
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I run this, it fails the privileges test--as expected--and makes the call to exec.  Checking if the call worked by looking at `p.isAlive()` shows that the process is, in fact, alive; however, I'm not seeing any evidence of the new process and Windows isn't prompting me to grant permissions.

I'm not familiar with using `exec()` in Java, so it's quite possible that I've misunderstood its usage somehow.  For that matter, is what I'm attempting to do here even possible?  If not, is there a straightforward alternative that will actually get me the results that I'm looking for?

Comment: In windows 8 (probably others as well), using `runas` doesn't actually bring up a UAC popup, but instead it prompts for the password to be entered through stdin.  Try running `runas /profile /user:Administrator notepad` in a command prompt window; that may explain your issue.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the case here.  I suppose that this just leads to a follow up question: how can I bring up a UAC popup in Java?

Alternatively, my target platform is Windows 7 (even though I'm developing on a Windows 8 platform).  Will this code do what I'm intending on that platform?

Comment: One solution would be to write a simple application in C to relaunch your Java program for you.  You can give the application an application manifest to tell Windows that elevation is required.  However, there may well be a way to do it directly in Java, and it's an interesting question.  +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've finally managed to get a solution for this problem that I'm happy with; it's a bit on the ugly side, but it works for what I'm doing.

I borrowed the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11042773/1202686) answer to do the actual privilege elevation; from there, the question was one of actually getting that solution to work with Java.  The code for that ends up looking like this:

```
    if (!checkPrivileges()) {
        try {
            String jarPath = DownloaderMain.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
            String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(jarPath, "UTF-8");
            decodedPath = decodedPath.substring(1, decodedPath.length());
            Elevator.executeAsAdministrator(System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\java", "-jar " + "\"" + decodedPath + "\"");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // Run with elevated privileges
    }
```

The `checkPrivileges` method is unchanged from above and the `Elevator` class is virtually identical to the one that appears in the linked solution (I just took out the unneeded `main` method).  This solution assumes that the process to be elevated is a jar; it shouldn't be too difficult to change this around to suit your individual needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach to achieve this is to use the tools that microsoft built for developers since you can't do it in simple Java. In this case use a manifest file 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632(v=vs.85).aspx
Just build the wrapper .exe that asks for this privileges and then spawns your java program.