# WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody:

Tags: java, google-drive-api

When running the Java quickstart sample at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java?hl=hu in NetBeans, I'm receiving the error code:

```
Jun 04, 2015 12:12:11 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody:
C:\Users\Quibbles\credentials\drive-api-quickstart
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is the complete error message.

```
Jun 04, 2015 5:11:39 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Quibbles\.credentials\drive-api-quickstart
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at DriveQuickstart.authorize(DriveQuickstart.java:64)
    at DriveQuickstart.getDriveService(DriveQuickstart.java:87)
    at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:96)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please post the complete warning.

Comment: Your service might be already running. Kill the old instance, than it should work again.

Comment: @KRR I updated the post to include the other error messages I am receiving. It happens without the service already running.

Comment: I have the same problem under windows 10.

Answer (score 35):

Had the same issue and wasted hours before realizing that "unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Quibbles.credentials\drive-api-quickstart"
is just a warning.

The real issue is the null pointer here.

```
InputStream in =
            DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
```

This line was the issue in my case. "in" was null and hence the null pointer.

```
InputStream in    = new FileInputStream("<Full Path>\\client_secret.json");
```

This resolved my issue.

Comment: Had the same issue in "google-api-java-client-samples-master". Here you should do `InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("<Full Path>\\client_secrets.json"));` Because `GoogleClientSecrets.load` only does not accept a `InputStream`.

Answer (score 18):

The actual problem is a bug in Google's API code for setPermissionsToOwnerOnly

The code was written to only work on Linux/Unix based systems and not Windows ACL based systems.

You can ignore the warning or write your own DataStore class that sets the permissions correctly for Windows.

I'm going to try to file a bug with Google on it too.

Comment: Source problem is at this GitHub repo owned by Google.   Code hasn't been updated since 2013.  https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/blob/dev/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/store/FileDataStoreFactory.java

Comment: I've submitted a bug issue report to Google:   https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/315

Comment: To disable the WARNING message caused by the Google library code bug use:

   final java.util.logging.Logger buggyLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FileDataStoreFactory.class.getName());
   buggyLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue in Eclipse. Here’s a solution:

1. Run eclipse in admin mode
2. Clear the directory 
   `C:/Users/<username>.credentials/calendar-java-quickstart.json`
3. Copy the .json file the bin directory, e.g. `bin/main/resources/client_secret.json`

You are free to run now.

Answer (score 3):

Basically if you already enabled de Drive API and created  credentials.json file at [Google Drive API Rest](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java), now you need :

1 - Remove the **tokens** directory generated in you last execution. In this directory contains a file StoredCredential.
2 - Change de **SCOPE** to **DriveScopes.DRIVE** like sample bellow:

private static List SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

3 - Re run the program. It will be request that you login in your google account to give the access consent.

4 - It will be generated a new one tokens directory in your project and now with  with read and write permissions at google Drive.

This work for me.

Comment: most helpful answer for me

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue with the https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java example. I suspect that the issue is that you are running it in Windows and the JVM that you are running it does not have Adminsitrator rights for changing the file permissions in Windows.

See [Run Java application as administrator on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664176/run-java-application-as-administrator-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when running the example given in the tutorial "https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/java". Followed the instruction ditto as given the in the tutorial, but kept getting this permission exception. Eventually, managed to sort it out by moving the "client_secret.json" to the "\build\classes\main\classes" folder. Also, before building the project with "gradle -q run" for the first time, delete any files in the  "C:\Users\userName\.credentials" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that client_secret.json is under main/resources/ directory.[image]

```
InputStream in =
            DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/client_secret.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the issue by deleting the StoredCredentials files under the token folder. I had to reauthenticate again with google the next time the program was executed.