# Google drive api only returning files the code uploaded

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to figure out the basics of the google drive api for a project that will kick off soon.

However, the `drive.file.list().execute()` only returns the files that were uploaded by the api. (e.g. the txt file i pushed to the drive to test)
None of the files in the drive that were uploaded manually are returned in the FilesList.

```
String pageToken = null;  
Drive.Files.List qry = drive.files().list();  

FileList list = qry.execute();
```

The list only contains the two files that were uploaded by the api.
Tried finding a solution online, but could not find a similar situation.

There are no errors, only the warnings for being unable to set the permissions.
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634827/warning-unable-to-change-permissions-for-everybody) claims that this warning is because I am on a windows system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Posting incase someone has the same problem in the future.

The problem was an incorrect scope when instantiating `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`. (you need to change the `DriveScopes.---` in the case of java)