# IllegalArgumentException when authenticating using Google's Java API client library

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to run QuickStart.java https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java on NetBeans 8.2. I've imported all the Google Libraries and I'm having this issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.<init>(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:197)
at Quickstart.authorize(Quickstart.java:71)
at Quickstart.getSheetsService(Quickstart.java:90)
at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:98)
C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I'd tried what's mention on [WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634827/warning-unable-to-change-permissions-for-everybody), but didn't work. My code is the following:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\Excel\\client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
        // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        String spreadsheetId = "1giT9gM-xYs1UriAw6yFLfJ2ZYgvPzNMHyKr5R2j1ZII";
        String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Name, Major");
          for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That question you link is completely unrelated to your own - did you read the error message you are getting, versus what they were getting? Given your error, you are passing the wrong arguments to `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder`. Are your arguments correct? Specifically, there is an issue with your GoogleClientSecrets.

Comment: @tehhowch Yes I'm passing the correct arguments to `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder`, I don't know how to fix the error that's why I posted it in here. I did a lot of research and found nothing.

Comment: what debugging steps have you done? When you split the flow builder into multiple steps (first making the builder, then calling builder methods, then building), which one gives the error? Is your `client_secrets` file the correct format?

Comment: @tehhowch I just download the `client_secrets.json` from google API page and I follow the steps. It should work

Comment: when something "should work" but does not, you **must** debug. The error message says there are illegal arguments to a specific function. Thus your task is to verify (not assume) that your inputs are what is required. If you are using a generic file and not one with specific information that is unique to your application, that would be an error you are making.

Answer (score 16):

I also ran through the same error. 
I have been using **Service account keys** instead of **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**

Using the OAuth 2.0 client IDs fetched from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ worked and was able to read the sheet.

Comment: This was the solution for me, thank you. Only want to add that the OAuth consent screen has to be configured beforehand which is a pain... And don't forget to set the redirect URI's if you are testing from a local machine, otherwise the permission dialog will not show correctly.

Comment: For localhost you need usually set up callback "http://localhost:8888/Callback" on your credentials.json for OAuth 2.0 client ID.