# Create a folder in "Program Files" directory of Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, operating-system, filesystems

When my java program is executing it's creating a directory in "**Program Files**". But access denied "**Program Files**" folder to create a folder. According to my knowledge the application is running with current user and it should be executed with Administrator privileges. How can acquire Administrator privileges when creating folder or files via java code ?

> This is what I have used code and ***directory_location*** is as
>   follows
>
> *C:/Program Files/*

```
public int createDirectory(String directory_location) {
        int done = 0;

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(directory_location));
            done = 1;
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            Log.getInstance().writeMethodeException(FileSystemConfig.rootFolder, ioEx);
        }
        return done;
    }
```

Comment: Start your program as administrator

Comment: If you run the java program with administrator rights you should be able to do that

Comment: If you ever launch your java program from a DOS console, you may want to open the console with administrator rights : _Start > cmd > right click > run as administrator._

Comment: The question really is why?  Even as administrator, you may not be able to create directories in the Program Files directory, particularly under Windows 8 and 10, as running the way the security mechanisms have changed and you may run into other issues you wouldn't otherwise expect. If you're just trying to write configuration, then write it to the `{user.home}\AppData\{Local or Roaming}\{program}` directory

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26706333/4101906)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable consultation @MadProgrammer and I want to create configuration files and log files then you prefer to do that in AppData .

Comment: @ChamindaBandara  Convention would suggest this as been the preferred way