# How to add system property to exe file in java

Tags: java, system-properties

I have a project in java, which i want to run only if the user is admin, for that I set system property to admin - `-Duser=admin`

I export my project to a jar and create its exe.

How can i set system property for exe file?
How to verify if user is admin, easy in case of batch file but unable to do for exe file.

User admin does not mean windows admin user, i want to make certain people admin and use some specific features of my application.

Comment: why would you want an exe file? what do you mean by 'system property file'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if Java application was run as a Windows admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350356/detect-if-java-application-was-run-as-a-windows-admin)

Comment: @Stultuske I have not referred system property file, I am talking about system properties in java which we can set with help of -D. I need exe for safety purpose, if I give it as jar to clients ,it can be decompiled. Not completely secure but a better way

Comment: @chetnarustagi and you think an .exe can't be re-engineered/decompiled? the only way to make sure nobody gets to your code, is by not distributing it at all, only providing a client that calls your business logic

Comment: @AndreasHartmann Not for windows admin user, say i want to add another system property, making it admin is just an example

Comment: @Stultuske yes, agree.

Comment: You didn't mention which tool you are using to produce .exe file. Maybe the tool support page has the answer.

Comment: @yegodm launch4j , thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating exe via `launch4j` , under `JRE` tab, we can define system properties in `JVM Options` as `-Duser=admin`

This will be same as defining any system property in run configurations of eclipse.